# C# WPF add Navigation Handler to DataGridHyperlinkColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm having a problem with a WPF C# .NEt 4.5 application.

I'm programmatically creating a DataGridHyperlinkColumn inside a Grid.

Meaning that almost nothing is written in the xaml file but created directly by the .cs

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Path" Binding="{Binding Path=FullPath}" ContentBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*">
   <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style>
         <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="hyperlink_Click"/>
      </Style>
   </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

With this code I'm able to populate my Grid with links, which when clicked will activate my `hyperlink_Click` function.

Now if I'll do this by code the result is the following:

```
        DataGridHyperlinkColumn parent = new DataGridHyperlinkColumn
        {
            Binding = new Binding("ParentName"),
        };
```

But now I'm not able to attach a `new RequestNavigateEventHandler(hyperlink_Click)` to each link which will populate my Grid.

At the current time my grid is populate with links, that are not possibile to be clicked.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the equivalent of your XAML:

```
Style style = new Style();
style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(Hyperlink.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(hyperlink_Click)));
DataGridHyperlinkColumn parent = new DataGridHyperlinkColumn
{
    Header = "Path",
    Binding = new Binding("FullPath"),
    ContentBinding = new Binding("Name"),
    IsReadOnly = true,
    ElementStyle = style
};
```